# How to find average of innerHTMLs?

Tags: javascript, html

I have input fields and selects. For different select options there are different equations. After calculating equations, I used .innerHTML to show results. I got first part of the code worked, but I am stuck at the last part. When I try to calculate average of outputs, It shows Nan. Can anyone help with this problem? Thanks in advance.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var span1 = document.getElementById('span1');
var span2 = document.getElementById('span2');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function average() {
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('a').value);
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('b').value);
  var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById('c').value);
  var d = parseFloat(document.getElementById('d').value);

  if (document.getElementById('select1').value == '1') {
    span1.innerHTML = ((a+b)/(a*b)).toFixed(2);
  } else if (document.getElementById('select1').value == '2') {
    span1.innerHTML = ((a*b)/(a+b)).toFixed(2)
  } else {
    span1.innerHTML = '';
  }

  if (isNaN(span1.innerHTML)) {
    span1.innerHTML = '';
  }

  if (document.getElementById('select1').value == 'none1') {
    span1.innerHTML = 'None'
  }

  if (document.getElementById('select2').value == '3') {
    span2.innerHTML = ((c+d)*100/(c*d)).toFixed(2);
  } else if (document.getElementById('select2').value == '4') {
    span2.innerHTML = ((c*d)*100/(c+d)).toFixed(2)
  } else {
    span2.innerHTML = '';
  }

  if (isNaN(span2.innerHTML)) {
    span2.innerHTML = '';
  }

  if (document.getElementById('select2').value == 'none2') {
    span2.innerHTML = 'None'
  }

  var percent = document.getElementsByClassName('percent');
  for (var i = 0; percent.length > i; i++) {
    if (percent.length > 0) {
      output.innerHTML = percent[i]/(percent.length);
    }
  }
}

container.addEventListener('change', average);
container.addEventListener('input', average);
```

```html
<div id="container">
            <input id="a" type="number">
            <input id="b" type="number">
            <select name="abc" id="select1">
                    <option value="Choose">Choose...</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="none1">None</option>
                </select>
            <br>
            <input id="c" type="number">
            <input id="d" type="number">
            
            <select name="abcd" id="select2">
                    <option value="Choose">Choose...</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="none2">None</option>
                </select>
   <span id="span1" class="percent"></span>
   <span id="span2" class="percent"></span><br>
   <span id="output"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I cant understand, that you doing, explain me and i will help you

Comment: If anything in your input fields isn't a valid number, `parseFloat` will return `NaN` and ruin your whole average. Check if a, b, c, or d `isNan` and alert the user to fix the number

Comment: I am sorry If my question is not clear. I would like to find average of results. For example, If output of span1 = 5 and output of span2 = 7, I would like to find average of them (like (5+7)/2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you're trying to do, but I think this might be the correct solution it's a working way of getting the value of the percent[i] HTML element:

Change

```
output.innerHTML = percent[i]/(percent.length);
```

to

```
output.innerHTML = percent.item(i).innerHTML/(percent.length);
```

or

```
output.innerHTML = percent[i].innerHTML/(percent.length);
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer because you never to math with the value of `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Works in Firefox at least.

Answer (score 1):

`.innerHTML` gets or sets the content of an element by invoking the HTML parser on the string passed as the value or extracted from the element. When the content is, or is to become just text (no HTML to be parsed), you should use `.textContent` as this will not invoke the HTML parser on the content, which saves processing power. In your case, you should be using `.textContent`.

Now, either way, data sent to or gotten from either `.innerHTML` or `.textContent` is a string, so if you want to do math with the value, you need to first convert it to a number. This can be done in several ways:

- `parseInt(stringToBeConverted, radix)`
- `parseFloat(stringToBeConverted)`
- `Number(stringToBeConverted)`
- `+stringToBeConverted`

**Now, you have two issues**, first when some of the text fields are still empty, their value is an empty string and `parseFloat()` on an empty string returns `NaN`. This can be solved by giving each field a default value of `0` in the HTML (i.e. `<input id="a" type="number" value="0">`).

Second, even with `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` all having numeric values, your math:

```
((a + b) / (a * b)).toFixed(2);
```

Will result in `NaN` when `a * b` results in `0` because that will result in a division by zero situation.

You need to change your algorithm to test for this situation before doing the math.